# create a column with values from other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
Day1 Day2 Day3 Day4 ID Product Price
     Day2      Day4 2  X       50
Day1      Day3 Day4 3  Y       60
     Day2 Day3      4  Z       70
```

I want it to be aggregated in this way

```
Days           ID Product  Price
Day2&Day4      2  X        50
Day1&Day3&Day4 3  Y        60 
Day2&Day3      4  Z        70
```

I am finding it difficult to crack the logic behind this

Raw input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Day1': ['', 'Day1', ''],
                   'Day2': ['Day2', '', 'Day2'],
                   'Day3': ['', 'Day3', 'Day3'],
                   'Day4': ['Day4', 'Day4', ''],
                   'ID': [2, 3, 4],
                   'Product': ['X', 'Y', 'Z'],
                   'Price': [50, 60, 70]})
```

Comment: what is in the empty cells?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the relevant columns to a list of lists and use list comprehension where in each iteration, you filter out empty spaces and join the remaining items with `&` in between. Then assign this list of strings to `'Days'` column. Finally, drop the redundant columns and rearrange remaining columns in your preferred order.

```
cols = ['Day1', 'Day2', 'Day3', 'Day4']
df['Days'] = ['&'.join(x for x in lst if x!='') for lst in df[cols].to_numpy().tolist()]
df = df.drop(cols, axis=1)[['Days','ID','Product','Price']]
```

Output:

```
             Days  ID Product  Price
0       Day2&Day4   2       X     50
1  Day1&Day3&Day4   3       Y     60
2       Day2&Day3   4       Z     70
```

Answer (score -1):

I have fully automated version. A bit more code lines, but works.
I find all columns that startswith "Day" phrase, then concatinate them, then drop the old columns and reorder columns.

```
cols = df.columns[pd.Series(df.columns).str.startswith('Day')]
df['Days'] = df[cols].apply('&'.join, axis=1).str.strip('&')
df.drop(columns = cols, inplace = True)
col = df.pop("Days")
df.insert(0, col.name, col)
# To clear double '&' chars.
import re
df['Days'] = [re.sub('&+', '&', day) for day in df['Days']]
```

Comment: `df['Days'].str.replace('&+', '&', regex=True)` ;)

Comment: @mozway Nice, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

*NB. Assuming your empty cells are 'NaN', if not you can use `df.replace({'': float('nan')})` as a first step*

You could `stack` and `groupby`+`apply('&'.join)`:

```
df['Days'] = df.filter(like='Day').stack().groupby(level=0).apply('&'.join)
```

The stacking operation gets rid of the empty cells

output:

```
   Day1  Day2  Day3  Day4  ID Product  Price            Days
0   NaN  Day2   NaN  Day4   2       X     50       Day2&Day4
1  Day1   NaN  Day3  Day4   3       Y      6  Day1&Day3&Day4
2   NaN  Day2  Day3   NaN   4       Z     70       Day2&Day3
```

###### dropping the original DaysX columns:

```
cols = list(df.filter(like='Day').columns)
df['Days'] = df[cols].stack().groupby(level=0).apply('&'.join)
df.drop(columns=cols)
```

output:

```
   ID Product  Price            Days
0   2       X     50       Day2&Day4
1   3       Y      6  Day1&Day3&Day4
2   4       Z     70       Day2&Day3
```